# is there a book which tells how some commands such as "ls" works with linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

i want to know details about these commands working with kernel ,if some guys can introduce such books.
for example ,i type "ls" in command line console ,i want to know how linux kernel handles this command and so on.

Comment: The kernel doesn't handle commands directly.

Comment: What did you try? Did you search for some books already?

Comment: Have a look at "ls" source code. It's simple.

Answer (score 2):

You may try "Linux Kernel in a Nutshell":
http://www.kroah.com/lkn/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a list of bash commands: [Bash commands](http://ss64.com/bash/).

Alternatively you could read man pages: in your terminal just type `man` followed by the command (without arguments) you want to learn more about. Example:

```
$ man ls
```

Here's the first part of the output:

```
LS(1)                            User Commands                           LS(1)

NAME
       ls - list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
       ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       List  information  about  the FILEs (the current directory by default).
       Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort  is  speci‐
       fied.

...
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way to find out (if you know some C), is to run `strace -o <file-name> <command>`. This will show you all of the system calls that are made by the command. It shows how these commands interact with both the kernel and the standard library. Note however, that you can't run this on all *commands*: only on *programs*, so to check out a shell command you might try `strace -o <file> sh -c <command>`.

Btw, in case you don't know C: you can look up the functions named in the strace output in the man pages, too: e.g. `man read`